# EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/....."

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create AWS RDS and deploy lambda function using a python script. However, I am getting below error, looks like it is unable to communicate with the aws commands to create rds.

```
DEBUG: Caught retryable HTTP exception while making metadata service request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/"

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 303, in _get_request
 response = self._session.send(request.prepare())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 282, in send raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)

EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/"
```

I am getting the aws credentials through SSO okta. In the ~/.aws directory,below are the contents of 'credentials' and 'config' file respectively.

````
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <Key Id>
aws_secret_access_key = <Secret Key>
aws_session_token = <Token>

[default]
region = us-west-2

```python
```
for az in availability_zones:
    if aurora.get_db_instance(db_instance_identifier + "-" + az)[0] != 0:
        aurora.create_db_instance(db_cluster_identifier, db_instance_identifier + "-" + az, az, subnet_group_identifier, db_instance_type)
    else:
        aurora.modify_db_instance(db_cluster_identifier, db_instance_identifier + "-" + az, az, db_instance_type)

# Wait for DB to become available for connection
iter_max = 15
iteration = 0
for az in availability_zones:
    while aurora.get_db_instance(db_instance_identifier + "-" + az)[1]["DBInstances"][0]["DBInstanceStatus"] != "available":
        iteration += 1
        if iteration < iter_max:
            logging.info("Waiting for DB instances to become available - iteration " + str(iteration) + " of " + str(iter_max))
            time.sleep(10*iteration)
        else:
            raise Exception("Waiting for DB Instance to become available timed out!")

cluster_endpoint = aurora.get_db_cluster(db_cluster_identifier)[1]["DBClusters"][0]["Endpoint"]
````

The actual error below, coming from the while loop, DEBUG shows unable to locate credential, but the credential is there. I can deploy an Elastic Beanstalk environment from cli using the same aws credential, but not this. Looks like the above aurora.create_db_instance command failed.

```
DEBUG: Unable to locate credentials

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./deploy_api.py", line 753, in <module> sync_rds()
  File "./deploy_api.py", line 57, in sync_rds
    while aurora.get_db_instance(db_instance_identifier + "-" + az)[1]["DBInstances"][0]["DBInstanceStatus"] != "available":

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because an ECS task didn't have permissions to write to DynamoDB. The code causing the problem was:

from boto3 import resource

dynamodb_resource = resource("dynamodb")

The problem was resolved when I filled in the region_name, aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key parameters for the resource() function call.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource

If this doesn't solve your problem then check your code that connects to AWS services and make sure that you are filling in all of the proper function parameters.